# c++ => curl compile errors

Tags: c++, curl

I have problems with the compilation of curl, it would be great if 
sb could help me with that.

I used an example code from curl:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h> 



int main(int argc, char **argv){
    CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
  //curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://postit.example.com/moo.cgi");
    /* Now specify the POST data */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=daniel&project=curl");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

But getting this compiler error:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curl_easy_init'
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curl_easy_setopt'
main.cpp:(.text+0x51): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curl_easy_setopt'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5d): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curl_easy_perform'
main.cpp:(.text+0x70): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curl_easy_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x98): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curl_easy_cleanup'
main.cpp:(.text+0x9d): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curl_global_cleanup'
```

What means, that the functions are not linked.

Maybe I forgot something to install?
I show u the process, how I installed curl now:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.53.1.tar.gz
sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.53.1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf curl-7.53.1.tar.gz 
sudo tar -xvzf curl-7.53.1.tar.gz 
sudo rm *.gz
cd curl-7.53.1/
./configure 
sudo ./configure 
sudo make
sudo make install
```

No angry google it reacts, pls.
I already googled it very long.

Comment: Have you linked you program to curl? For gcc, -l should be in your command line.

Comment: You need to link in `libcurl`.

Comment: how and what should I  link in libcurl?

Comment: I use -lcurl in terminal it's working, thx.

Comment: But how can I compile without using -lcurl everytime?